# What's the ideal way to trim extra spaces from a string?

Tags: string, rust, replace, whitespace

I'm dealing with strings where I need to replace multiple spaces    with just a single space  . It looks like most of these are just human error, but am curious on the ideal way to handle this -- preferrably with the least allocations from `&str` to `String`.

So far this is my approach below:

```
const SPACE: &str = " ";
const TWO_SPACES: &str = "  ";

/// Replace multiple spaces with a single space
pub fn trim_whitespace(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut new_str: String = s.trim().to_owned();
    while new_str.contains(TWO_SPACES) {
        new_str = new_str.replace(TWO_SPACES, SPACE);
    }
    new_str
}

let result = trim_whitespace("Hello     world! ");
assert_eq!(result, "Hello world!");
```

---

*Edit (10/2022)*: I come from a background in Python, where doing something like the above is quite idiomatic. For example, the [fastest version](https://gist.github.com/rnag/7c2e0cbd76a0af484009428d03b7bff2) in Python (to replace multiple spaces with a single space) appears to be this:

```py
def trim_whitespace(s: str) -> str:
    s = s.strip()
    while '  ' in s:
        s = s.replace('  ', ' ')
    return s
```

Comment: Well the question is what is it that you are trying to optimize. In your while loop the string is traversed multiple times, rather than once. You are already making a copy in new_str and "replace" itself has a traversal so you have two loops internally why not do it as a vector?

Comment: Well, so basically the input and result can be either `&str` or `String`, doesn’t matter too much either way. I know the multiple `replace` might not be best, but am just wondering how I can improve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`split_whitespace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_whitespace) is very convenient for this usage.

A vector and a string are allocated in the very simple first solution.

The second solution allocates only a string, but is a bit inelegant (an `if` at each iteration).

```rust
pub fn trim_whitespace_v1(s: &str) -> String {
    // first attempt: allocates a vector and a string
    let words: Vec<_> = s.split_whitespace().collect();
    words.join(" ")
}

pub fn trim_whitespace_v2(s: &str) -> String {
    // second attempt: only allocate a string
    let mut result = String::with_capacity(s.len());
    s.split_whitespace().for_each(|w| {
        if !result.is_empty() {
            result.push(' ');
        }
        result.push_str(w);
    });
    result
}

fn main() {
    let source = "  a   bb cc   ddd    ";
    println!("{:?}", trim_whitespace_v1(source)); // "a bb cc ddd"
    println!("{:?}", trim_whitespace_v2(source)); // "a bb cc ddd"
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize `split_whitespace()` does not work like `split()` and does not yield empty entries. Pedantically, however, it doesn't only strip spaces so it isn't the same as OP's code (though it is what the title requests).

Comment: yep, I would agree that white spaces generally aren't a concern in the type of strings I'm dealing with. To elaborate, they're basically video titles, for example titles of videos that go on Youtube, so spaces are only the real thing I care about. The stripping of newlines is acceptable, but not really a concern since the strings won't have them any way.

Comment: just wanted to say I found the `trim_ whitespace_v2` to be quite idiomatic, and in fact i actually updated my code to use a modified version of it. I found these to both be excellent answers, however I went with one from @Chayim since I had to choose just one.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `split(' ')`, filter out empty entries then re-join by space:

```rust
s.trim()
    .split(' ')
    .filter(|s| !s.is_empty())
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .join(" ")

// Or, using itertools:
use itertools::Itertools;
s.trim().split(' ').filter(|s| !s.is_empty()).join(" ")
```

Another possibility is to use [`String::retain()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.retain) and remove consecutive spaces. It should also be faster since it allocates only once, for the trimmed string:

```rust
pub fn trim_whitespace(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut new_str = s.trim().to_owned();
    let mut prev = ' '; // The initial value doesn't really matter
    new_str.retain(|ch| {
        let result = ch != ' ' || prev != ' ';
        prev = ch;
        result
    });
    new_str
}
```

---

**Edit:** I was curious and so I benchmarked all versions suggested here with the string `"  a   bb cc   ddd    "` (of course, different strings will have different performance charateristics). Benchmark code is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a8c4847c4fc4e522e0ce5bfc1f0f30d) (requires `criterion` and `itertools`).

Results:

```
benches/trim_whitespace_replace
                        time:   [846.02 ns 872.71 ns 901.90 ns]
benches/trim_whitespace_retain
                        time:   [146.79 ns 153.07 ns 159.91 ns]
benches/trim_whitespace_split_space
                        time:   [268.61 ns 277.44 ns 287.55 ns]
benches/trim_whitespace_split_space_itertools
                        time:   [392.82 ns 406.92 ns 423.88 ns]
benches/trim_whitespace_split_whitespace
                        time:   [236.38 ns 244.51 ns 254.00 ns]
benches/trim_whitespace_split_whitespace_itertools
                        time:   [395.82 ns 413.59 ns 433.26 ns]
benches/trim_whitespace_split_whitespace_only_one_string
                        time:   [146.25 ns 152.73 ns 159.94 ns]
```

As expected, your version using `replace()` is the slowest. My versions using `retain()` and @prog-fh's faster version are the fastest (I expected his version to be faster because it needs to copy less, but apparently the difference is very small and modern CPUs copy small blocks of memory very fast. Maybe in larger strings this will show up). Somewhat surprisingly, the versions using itertools' `join()` are slower than the versions that use only the standard library `collect()` then `join()`, despite not needing to first collect into a vector. I can explain it though - this versions use dynamic dispatch over `Display` the compiler may not be able to eliminate (I'm not sure though, need to check the assembly to verify), and worse, they may actually need to allocate more because they don't know the amount of space required ahead of time and they also need to insert the separator.

Comment: Oh man, you make it hard to choose the best answer here. I appreciate the benchmark code though, that looks pretty slick. I was also sure either the `retain` or the `String::with_capacity` approach would probably be the most optimized approach I could expect, and i'm glad to see that it is actually the case!

Comment: I wanted to suggest [`intersperse`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.intersperse) to insert the spaces back in the iterator, but surprisingly it is slower than your "only one string" solution: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6ad8f18f97bccd0c5d109d8b1d1566f6).

Comment: @Jmb I wouldn't benchmark in the playground. But it's expected it will be slower, since it cannot know the size of the allocation ahead of time.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Which is why I used `String::with_capacity` to allocate enough space up front.

Comment: @Jmb Oh haven't seen it. Strange.

Comment: If anyone's curious, I've done a quick and dirty comparison with the fastest `.replace` version in Python [here](https://gist.github.com/rnag/7c2e0cbd76a0af484009428d03b7bff2). I only tested for n=10_000 loop iterations, but I think that should be a good enough idea. Minor spoiler, but the Rust version with "one string" seems to be about 2-3x faster on average, which was somewhat surprising to me.